DAX script for measure based on date dimention
In SSAS I have the fact table:



ContractID
DateFrom
DateTo




1001
2024-06-01
2024-06-20


1002
2024-06-05
2024-06-10


1002
2024-06-15
2024-07-10


1003
2024-06-20
2024-08-05



and Date dimention:



Year
MonthName
MonthId
Date




2024
June
6
2024-06-01


2024
June
6
2024-06-02



...
There is no relationship between the fact table and Date dimention.
I need to create a measure with a unique count of ContractID, where Date value (Date dimention) between DateFrom and DateTo (fact table). The measure should work when choosing any date level from Date dimention: year, year-month, year-month-date.
CountOfContracts :=
CALCULATE(
           DISTINCTCOUNT('FactTable'[ContractId]),
           FILTER('FactTable',
                     (
                        SELECTEDVALUE('DateDimention'[Date]) >= 'FactTable'[DateFrom] &&
                        SELECTEDVALUE('DateDimention'[Date]) <= 'FactTable'[DateTo]
                     )
                  )
         )

Problem: this doesn't work with date at month and year level

Might be easier if you expanded the DateFrom and DateTo to individual dates. Then join that result to the calendar table and then this is simple. If you convert the dates to Integers, you can use a List, and then convert the list to a table.

@Pieter What do you mean by expand the DateFrom and DateTo? Do you mean create a new column in FactTable called Date, then creating 2 rows for a ContractID, one for DateFrom and another for DateTo?

Pieter, thanks for the advice, I was thinking of doing the same, but there is a risk of greatly increasing the size of the fact table. This is how I managed to solve the problem:
CountOfContracts :=
var MonthId = LOOKUPVALUE('DateDimention'[year_month_order/* format YYYYMM */],'DateDimention'[Year], SELECTEDVALUE('DateDimention'[Year]), 'DateDimention'[MonthId], SELECTEDVALUE('DateDimention'[MonthId]))
return
switch
(
    true,
    HASONEVALUE('DateDimention'[Year]) && not HASONEVALUE('DateDimention'[MonthId]),
                 CALCULATE(
                            DISTINCTCOUNT('FactTable'[ContractID]),
                FILTER('FactTable',
                (
                    SELECTEDVALUE('DateDimention'[Year]) >= year('FactTable'[DateFrom]) &&
                    SELECTEDVALUE('DateDimention'[Year]) <= year('FactTable'[DateTo])
                )
                      )
            ), 

                HASONEVALUE('DateDimention'[MonthId]) && not HASONEVALUE('DateDimention'[Date]),
        CALCULATE(
               DISTINCTCOUNT('FactTable'[ContractID]),
                FILTER('FactTable',
                (
                    MonthId >= year('FactTable'[StartDate])*100 + month('FactTable'[DateFrom]) &&
                    MonthId <= year('FactTable'[EndDate])*100 + month('FactTable'[DateTo])
                )
                )
            ),

        HASONEVALUE('DateDimention'[Date]),
        CALCULATE(
              DISTINCTCOUNT('FactTable'[ContractID]),
                FILTER('FactTable',
                (
                    SELECTEDVALUE('DateDimention'[Date]) >= 'FactTable'[DateFrom] &&
                    SELECTEDVALUE('DateDimention'[Date]) <= 'FactTable'[DateTo]
                )
                )
            ),

        BLANK()
)


SELECTEDVALUE will return only the one value from your DateDim, where what you need is to get the range of dates from DateDim. You can do that with MIN and MAX.
For example:
CountOfContracts :=
  CALCULATE(
    DISTINCTCOUNT('FactTable'[ContractId]),
    FILTER('FactTable',
      MAX('DateDimention'[Date]) >= 'FactTable'[DateFrom] &&
      MIN('DateDimention'[Date]) <= 'FactTable'[DateTo]
    )
  )


Nick,
What I mean is that instead of keeping 1 and 5 as the start and end of your range, you expand that to {1,2,3,4,5}.
have you played with lists in PowerQuery yet? (Maybe not). The trick is that the work with integers. So you go into PowerQuery and convert your dates to integers. Then you create a column that's [StartDateNumber]..[EndDateNumber] and then you expand the list. Now you should have one record for each date number. Then convert the numeric column back to a date.
Here's an example. My original data is two rows:
Person, StartDate, EndDate
Fred, 1/1/2023, 12/31/2023
Bill, 6/1/2023, 12/31/2023
so when I expand them, Fred will have 365 days of records, and Bill will have 7 months of records (so like 210 days).
Here's the PowerQuery:
let
Source = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("i45WcitKTVHSUTLUN9Q3MjAyBjGN9I2hnFidaCWnzJwcoKgZdgWxAA==", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [Person = _t, StartDate = _t, EndDate = _t]),
#"Converted Text Dates to Real Dates" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"StartDate", type date}, {"EndDate", type date}}),
#"Converted Dates To Integers" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Converted Text Dates to Integers",{{"StartDate", Int64.Type}, {"EndDate", Int64.Type}}),
#"Created DatesList to Expand the Start and EndDates" = Table.AddColumn(#"Converted Text Dates to Integers", "DatesList", each {[StartDate]..[EndDate]}),
#"Expanded DatesList" = Table.ExpandListColumn(#"Created DatesList to Expand the Start and EndDates", "DatesList"),
#"Converted DatesList column to Type Date" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Expanded DatesList",{{"StartDate", type date}, {"EndDate", type date}, {"DatesList", type date}})

in
#"Converted DatesList column to Type Date"
(if my stitching is okay, you should end up with a list of dates that start at StartDate and end at EndDate for the two records). Worked when I started... hopefully I didn't mess it up by renaming steps! But the main point is that you have to convert the dates columns to integer type, and then you can create a custom function to generate the list {[StartDateNumber]..[EndDateNumber]} and then you can expand that list and finally convert the numbers back to dates.
Then when you filter, your stuff will actually work.
